# Authentication relying on mysql_native_password seems to also check for Linux user?

Tags: authentication, mariadb-10.3

I have a mariaDB 10.3 install. The mysql.table states that 'root' login relies on mysql_native_password plugin, with no password set.

If my linux user is root, I am able to connect to mysql using;

```
mysql -u root -h localhost
```

If I login as a non privileged Linux user, when I try to connect to mysql, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Usually people having this issue have a plugin like unix_sock enabled (ex see [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)), but I don't. And by reading the [mysql_native_password doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-mysql_native_password/), I don't think the plugin is the issue. This plugin doesn't seem to rely on the Linux user to authenticate (I'm not native English, I may missed the point).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. Only the `root` account on most Linux-based systems can connect to MariaDB (and MySQL) as the `root` account. This is to prevent poor authentication practices as have been witnessed time and again where a WordPress (or any other CMS) installation uses the `root` database account, gets compromised, and gives the attackers full control over the database and every other website connecting to it.

If you would like to connect to MariaDB as `root` from a terminal connection, you will need to use `sudo`:

```
sudo mysql
```

In many situations, you will not need to specify the username here as it’s assumed the system admin for the server wants access to the `root` database account.

If you need an administrator-level account to manage the database from an external tool, such as PhpMyAdmin, TablePlus, or MySQL Workstation, you can create an account and grant appropriate privileges:

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

While this account can also be misused, like `'root'@'localhost'`, it is generally better practice to go this way.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer for now :S but thanks anyway ^^